# A prototype-less, new-less, one-instance-only javascript object?

Tags: javascript, singleton

This doesn't work.

```
var genericClickHandler = function () {
    this.handlers = [];
    if (console && console.log) {
        console.log("this:", this);
        console.log("event:", event);
    }
};

genericClickHandler.addHandler = function (handlerSpec) {
    this.handlers.push(handlerSpec);
    return this;
};

genericClickHandler.executeHandler = function (handlerName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.handlers.length; i++) {
        if (handlerName === this.handlers[i][0]) {
            this.handlers[i][1]();
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```

It doesn't work because the `addHandler` can't see the `this.handlers` in `genericClickHandler`.

Anyway what I'm after is function that gets defined once, but has methods and properties. I want to be able to use the function with Google Maps like this:

```
heatmap.addListener("click", genericClickHandler)
circle.addListener("click", genericClickHandler)
polygons.addListener("click", genericClickHandler)
```

So in the first instance, it only reports the `this` and `event` object. However, I then want to write code which extends the `genericClickHandler` dynamically so that it can implement map-object-specific behaviour.

Comment: Don't use a function, use an object and attach the methods to it.

Comment: @Andy I'm not sure I get what you're saying. If I code genericClickHandler = {}, then immediately I don't have something I can put in the addListener call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what I meant using an object rather than a function.

```
var genericClickHandler = {
    handlers: []
};

genericClickHandler.addHandler = function (name, fn) {
    this.handlers.push([name, fn]);
    return this;
};

genericClickHandler.executeHandler = function (name) {
   for (var i = 0, l = this.handlers.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (this.handlers[i][0] === name) this.handlers[i][1]();
   }
};

genericClickHandler.addHandler('click', function () {
  console.log('hi');
});

genericClickHandler.addHandler('click', function () {
  console.log('hallo again');
});

genericClickHandler.executeHandler('click'); // hi... hallo again
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fq68yfzm/2/)

Comment: That's good stuff, that. I was starting to think in terms of `.addListener("click", function (event) { genericClickHandler.Default(event) } )` and what you've got there would certainly work in that (after implementing `.Default`)

Comment: I see what you were trying to do now. I've put the array back.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create an object, here you can see 2 ways to do the same thing, javascript got multiple way to write the same things.

```
var genericClickHandler =  function()
{

this.handlers = [];

this.addHandler = function (handlerSpec)
    {
    this.handlers.push(handlerSpec);
    return this;
    },   

this.executeHandler = function (handlerName)
    {
    this.handlers[handlerName]();
    return this;
    }  

};

//sample:
var tmp = new genericClickHandler();
console.log(tmp.handlers);
console.log(tmp.addHandler("TEST"));
```

Another way to write the same object, but more optimised : prototype will be stored once for each object

```
var genericClickHandler = function(){}

genericClickHandler.prototype = 
    {
    handlers:[],

    addHandler : function (handlerSpec)
        {
        this.handlers.push(handlerSpec);
        return this;
        },

    executeHandler : function (handlerName)
        {
        this.handlers[handlerName]();
        return this;
        } 
    }

//sample:
var tmp = new genericClickHandler();
console.log(tmp.handlers);
console.log(tmp.addHandler("TEST"));
```

Comment: The benefit of @Andy's version over yours is that yours needs to be instantiated (with `new`).

Comment: yes, it depends of your needs, here you can have multiple objects without collision ;)